# How can I write those setStates with destructuring on one string?

Tags: reactjs, destructuring

React
`this.setState(({ images }) => ({ images: [...images, ...hits] }));`
`this.setState({ status: 'resolved', loading: false, totalHits });`
I'm trying to shorten those 2 setStates in one but I don't really understand how to do this, I tried to do it like
`this.setState(({ images }) => ({ images: [...images, ...hits] }), {status: 'resolved', loading: false, totalHits });`   but other states after images become callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this

```
this.setState(({ images }) => ({ images: [...images, ...hits], status: 'resolved', loading: false, totalHits });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
this.setState({
 images: [...this.state.images, ...hits],
 status: 'resolved',
 loading: false,
 totalHits
});
```

Comment: It works too but main point was how can I destructure it, thx anyway!